# Reversing order in 2D list in Python

Tags: python, list, reverse

I'd like to reverse specific dimensions of a list using list comprehension.  Suppose I have the following list:

```
test = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
```

I would like to return:

```
test = [[[4, 3], [2, 1]], [[8, 7], [6, 5]]]
```

The first set of the list are the same order, but both interior sets of lists are reversed.  I reversed the second layer successfully:

```
>>> [x[::-1] for x in [y for y in test]]
[[[3, 4], [1, 2]], [[7, 8], [5, 6]]]
```

But when I try:

```
>>> [z[::-1] for z in [x[::-1] for x in [y for y in test]]]
[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify, do you really want `[[[4, 3], [2, 1]], [[6, 5], [8, 7]]]`?  I would expect the `[6, 5]` and `[8, 7]` to be swapped, so `[[[4, 3], [2, 1]], [[8, 7], [6, 5]]]`

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo!  Will fix the original

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> test = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
>>> [[y[::-1] for y in x[::-1]] for x in test]
[[[4, 3], [2, 1]], [[8, 7], [6, 5]]]
```

Note that it would be slightly more efficient to use `reversed(x)` instead of `x[::-1]` because you wouldn't be creating an unnecessary temporary list, but `x[::-1]` is short an consistent with your current attempts.

As a side note, I find the list comprehensions significantly more readable but for the sake of completeness here is how you can do this with `map()`:

```
>>> map(lambda x: map(list, map(reversed, reversed(x))), test)
[[[4, 3], [2, 1]], [[8, 7], [6, 5]]]
```

Or on Python 3.x (since `map()` returns a map object instead of a list):

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: list(map(list, map(reversed, reversed(x)))), test))
[[[4, 3], [2, 1]], [[8, 7], [6, 5]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two separate list comprehensions, and the outside one is working on the output of the inside one. So it just reverse the same elements all over again. Instead, you need to have just one *nested* list comprehension:

```
[y[::-1] for x in test for y in x[::-1]]
```

Which is what I think you were aiming for in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

NumPy alternative:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(test)
>>> a[:,::-1,::-1].tolist()
[[[4, 3], [2, 1]], [[8, 7], [6, 5]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lists have the built-in function "reverse".  This is very convenient!

```
test = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]

for element in test:
    element.reverse()
    for entry in element:
        entry.reverse()
```

Results:

```
>>> test
[[[4, 3], [2, 1]], [[8, 7], [6, 5]]]
```